# jQuery 403 Forbidden when loading image

Tags: jquery, ajax, xampp

I'm trying to load an image into my modal plugin, but for some reason it's giving me a 403 Forbidden error. The actual error I get is this:

```
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost/Groundwork/%3Cimg%3E"
```

The image is in the root folder so I know it's there, I'm just not sure why it's having issues. If it matters I'm using XAMPP. Here's my modal code:

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.modal = function(userOptions)
    {
        var defaultOptions = 
        {
            size        :   null, 
            url         :   null,
            image       :   null 
        }

        options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, userOptions);

        $(this).addClass('modal-show');
        var id = $(this).data('modal-id');
        buildModal($(this), id);
    };

    function buildModal(element, id)
    {
        //  Create the modal window container
        var modalWindow = document.createElement('div');
        $(modalWindow).attr('id', id).addClass('modal');

        //  Create the modal body where we will load the external html/image
        var modalBody = document.createElement('div');
        $(modalBody).addClass('modal-body');

        //  If the user provides an external link/image then load that image into the modal body
        if (options.url && options.image == false)
        {
            $(modalBody).load(options.url);
        }

        else if (options.url && options.image == true)
        {
            var img = "<img>";
            $(img).attr('src', options.url);
            $(img).attr('alt', options.url);
            $(modalBody).load(img);
        }

        else
        {
            //  If the user doesn't not provide an external link or image then take the element
            //  calling this plugin and load it's contents into the modal
            $(modalBody).append(element.contents());
        }

        //  Create and add the close button
        var closeBtn = document.createElement('button');
        $(closeBtn).addClass('close');
        $(closeBtn).html('&times;');

        // Finally let's add the content to the modal itself
        $(modalWindow).append(modalBody);
        $('body').append(modalWindow);

        // Finally let's add the content to the modal itself
        $(modalWindow).append(modalBody);
        $(modalWindow).append(closeBtn);
        $('body').append(modalWindow);
    }

    function closeModal(id)
    {
        var modalID = '#' + id;

        //  Get the DOM that contains the modal so we can remove the backdrop
        var content = $('.modal-backdrop').contents();

        //  Have the backdrop and the modal fade out
        $(content).fadeOut();

        // Remove the backdrop from around the modal
        $('.modal-backdrop').replaceWith(content);  
    }

    function showModal(id)
    {
        var modalID = '#' + id;

        /*
        *   Add the backdrop around the modal (This is done primarily
        *   to make the developer's life easier so that they don't
        *   have to create the div for the backdrop.
        */
        $(modalID).wrapAll('<div class="modal-backdrop">');

        // Have the backdrop and the modal fade in
        $('.modal-backdrop').fadeIn().find(modalID).fadeIn();
    }

    $('body').on('click', '.modal-show', function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        //  Get the ID of the modal that we want to show
        var id = $(this).data('modal-id');
        showModal(id);
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.close', function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        //  Get the ID of the modal that we want to show
        var id = $(this).data('modal-id');

        closeModal(id);
    });
}
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

**Update:**

If I try to load options.url this is what happens:
[image: The Problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are sending encoded html `<img>`.

So your url looks like this:

```
http://localhost/Groundwork/<img>
```

Which is incorrect, there never be an image name like this.

So instead of specifying `<img>` tag inside `.load()` method, try `options.url` don't need to use `.load()` here.

```
var img = $('<img>').attr({
    src: options.url, 
    alt: options.url
});
$(modalBody).append(img);
```

Comment: I think the use of the angle braces for name of files and directories is not allowed.

Comment: Please refer to the update I made on the original post.

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted See my update. It doesn't make sense that if you know the url why you are loading it with `.load()`?

Comment: Because the .load() will load data from a url. An image afterall is data so I thought that was how I would need to do it. By appending the image to the modalBody that did remove the image data that I was seeing however now it's just loading a blank modal so I have to figure out why the image itself isn't loading.

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted That data itself is just image url which you already know its assigned to `options.url`. And make sure the url is correct if you are not seeing the image.

Comment: Got it..apparently the image was overwritten with another image that had nothing in it. So once I replaced the image it with something that actually had content it worked fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted If you consider this post helps atleast upvote or consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Sorry, meant to do that yesterday but forgot to.

Answer (score 2):

I can spot a couple of issues with this code block:

```
var img = "<img>";
$(img).attr('src', options.url);
$(img).attr('alt', options.url);
$(modalBody).load(img);
```

is creating a separate image element each time you do `$(img)`. jQuery operates on elements, not strings.

Second, [jQuery's `load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function loads a URL with AJAX, and places its result as text into the given element (which explains why you're getting the image data as text). You're passing it `img`, which is just the string `<img>`. Since what it looks like you're trying to do is insert the image into the element, what I think you want is:

```
var img = $("<img>");
img.attr('src', options.url);
img.attr('alt', options.url);
$(modalBody).append(img);
```